# How did "poll" ("top" or "head") semantically extend to "cut someone's hair"?

Tags: etymology

I don't understand this semantic extension (cf. [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=poll)) because it hasn't happened to "head" or "horn"! Unquestionably, "head" isn't the same thing as "cut someone's hair".

[Poll Definition and Meaning - Bible Dictionary](https://www.biblestudytools.com/dictionary/poll/)

> Neither shall they shave their heads, nor suffer their locks to grow long; they shall only **POLL** their heads. ( [Ezekiel 44:20](http://www.biblestudytools.com/ezekiel/44-20.html) )

E.g. you can't replace "poll" with "head", because "head" doesn't mean "cut someone's hair".

> Neither shall they shave their heads, nor suffer their locks to grow long; they shall only **HEAD???** their heads. ( [Ezekiel 44:20](http://www.biblestudytools.com/ezekiel/44-20.html) )

> #### poll [13]

> ‘Head’ is the original and central
> meaning of *poll*, from which all its modern uses
> have derived. The ‘voting’ sort of *poll*, for
> instance, which emerged in the 17th century, is
> etymologically a counting of ‘heads’, and the *poll tax* is a ‘per capita’ tax. The verb *poll*
> originally meant ‘cut someone’s hair’, a clear
> extension of the notion of ‘top’ or ‘head’ (the
> derived *pollard* [16] denotes an ‘animal with its
> horns removed’ or a ‘tree with its top branches
> cut off’); this later developed to ‘cut evenly
> across’, which is what the *poll* of *deed poll*
> means (originally it was a legal agreement cut
> evenly across, signifying that only one person
> was party to it – agreements made between two
> or more people were cut with a wavy line).

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto. p 385 Left column.

Comment: The answer is in your question: “*The verb poll originally meant ‘cut someone’s hair’, a clear extension of the notion of ‘top’ or ‘head’ (the derived pollard [16] denotes an ‘animal with its horns removed’ or a ‘tree with its top branches cut off’);*”

Comment: I don't know enough to answer, but is the word "poll" at the time of the translation what they would have used to describe what we now call the religious "tonsure" haircut, short on top but with longer hair on the side?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonsure

Comment: There are many ways to verb nouns. You can top a tree (meaning cut off its top) or top a salad (meaning put stuff on top of it). You can top your brother in height, or in a race, which means to score higher). You can top off the gas in your car, or you can top out at the highest number on a scale. And it goes on. One of the simplest is the "remove" sense (called "privative", because _deprive_): top a tree, skin a cat, seed and vein a pepper,_ etc. People do this instinctively with words -- if the meaning's clear in context, they'll use'em any way they want.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia: "Polled livestock are livestock without horns in species which are normally horned."[Polled livestock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polled_livestock) 
For an Old Testament prophet living in the time of animal sacrifice, it doesn't seem too much of a stretch for him to refer to cut hair as polled.

Just a few verses earlier he refers to the "uncircumcised in heart".

Comment: But Old Testament prophets didn't speak English.

Answer (score 0):

Compare *bald head*, and *bald*. I suppose you can synchronically form *to boldly bald someone where no man has balded before*.

I guess *to poll* may be similar. So far my thoughts a priori. This mostly disagrees with the quote that clearly distinguishes shaving from *to poll*, unless they distinguished only *shaving* the mustache specifically. If the quote is far removed from the original word (certainly not of biblical age), it might be indecisive.

The Ayto entry may have followed the written evidence, without giving too much consideration to semantics because it's actually not too difficult.

For analogy, consider **a)** German *Schopf*. As far as I understand it, that's lexically hair, a tuft or tail, but figuratively the whole head, metaphorically too (e.g. you have to grab the luck by the *Schopf*). **b)** Cp. *Frisur* "hair-do", *frisieren* "to do sb. hair", *Friseur* "coiffeur". Admittedly that's rather abstract, still, not exactly *top-hair*, but French *frisure* at least may mean "curl" (seems to come from Germanic but further origin uncertain, as are a surprising number of hairy words).

So (a) and (b) together allow to infer (*head ~ top hair*) > (*head dresser* ~ *barbar*) > (*to head* ~ *to do hair*) and all the same for *poll*.

By the way, I guess we may cp. *shape* and *scape*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Vectory corrected this now.